# Custom component check-in/check-out best practices

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

I'm creating a component in Joomla! 1.7 and I'd like to take advantage of the framework's check-out/check-in features.  Currently

- How do I mark a component record as "checked out" when a user requests the edit task for that record?
- How do I mark a record as "checked in" when the user attempts to store his or her edits?
- How do I test the checked-in/checked-out status of a component's record at edit time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicly you need two methods in your model, which you can call whenever you want to:

```
function checkin()
{
    if ($this->_id)
    {
        $item= & $this->getTable();
        if(! $item->checkin($this->_id)) {
            $this->setError($this->_db->getErrorMsg());
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function checkout($uid = null)
{
    if ($this->_id)
    {
        // Make sure we have a user id to checkout the article with
        if (is_null($uid)) {
            $user   =& JFactory::getUser();
            $uid    = $user->get('id');
        }
        // Lets get to it and checkout the thing...
        $item= & $this->getTable();
        if(!$item->checkout($uid, $this->_id)) {
            $this->setError($this->_db->getErrorMsg());
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

To mark item as checked, first of all you have to have column called `checked_out` with default value 0, also you need `checked_out_time` to store time, when item was checked out.
Hope it helps.